# Скрипт не срабатывает и выдает ошибку на простом while и if...elif

Tags: python, python-3.x, if, while

```
country = input('Выберите Техас, Ирландия или Норвегия')
while country != 'Ирландия' or 'Норвегия' or 'Техас':
    country = input('Выберите Техас, Ирландия или Норвегия')
if country == 'Ирландия':
    print('Ирландия это круто!')
elif country == 'Норвегия':
    print('Норвегия это круто!')
elif country == 'Техас':
    print('Техас это круто!')
```

Comment: Приведите больше подробностей - что вы вводите, что ожидаете, какая конкретно ошибка возникает.

Comment: Вводится 'Ирландия'

Comment: Даёт ошибку SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Comment: Когда указываете ошибку, также указывайте строку, на которую она указывает. У меня приведенный в вопросе код ошибку не вызывает.

Comment: Я через саблайм текст пишу, там нет идле, а в интерпритаторе не пишет на какой строке эта ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас как я понимаю 
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd0' in file t.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

попробуйте, для начала, в начало кода вставить:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало

Comment: ответ, который выше моего, не лишний)

Comment: @JassyPinkman на Python 3 вы не можете получить эту ошибку. Если вы пользуетесь Питон 2, то поправьте метки на вашем вопросе (вам следует тогда raw_input() использовать, а не input(), который на Питон 2 эквивалентен `eval(input())` из Питона 3).

Answer (score 1):

Вы неправильно понимаете построение логических выражений с помощью `or`.

```
while country != 'Ирландия' or 'Норвегия' or 'Техас':
```

Очевидно, вы ожидаете, что конструкция после while будет True, если country не равно ни одному слову из трёх перечисленных.

Однако, `!=` принимает после себя только один аргумент. И с помощью `or` действие этого оператора нельзя расширить. Чтобы проверять равенство переменной одному из нескольких значений, используйте `in`

```
while country not in ['Ирландия', 'Норвегия', 'Техас']:
```

Comment: Да, я заметил это пока ждал ответа но сделал не так как вы написали а ввел подругому:

Comment: while country != 'Ирландия' or country != 'Норвегия' or country != 'Техас':

Comment: Но спасибо за подсказку, не знал что можно таким образом это сделать.